# Sending envelopes from one dedicated user

Tags: docusignapi

I have been trying to implement JWT Auth grant for our back end application which will be creating URLs for signing operations for our end users.

What I want to active is that there will be no login/granting consent operations while sending the envelopes and creating signing URL. I want to dedicate one user for creating envelopes and sending them for signature.

Firstly, I've created a demo account and an organization. I also created an integration key and a RSA key. I needed to choose `Implicit Grant` or `Authorization Code Grant` while creating the integration key and I chose `Implicit Grant`. Lastly, I gave `signature impersonation` permissions to the integration key.

I have checked and made experiments with jwt example project after configuring with the required info of the user that I want to dedicate. It asked for the consent. After I gave consent, it worked finely. Then I configured the back end with the same integration key and the guid of the user, again it was working with our back end application that I was able to send automated envelopes.

I created another demo account in DS and this time I directly put it to our back end, I am getting `consent_required` error which I understand that I couldn't give the admin consent properly and it was just working with previous demo account because I gave the consent to that.

I want to know that how long that consent would last. or Is it the correct way to achieve what I want? because I think, ideally, I need to give admin consent to this dedicated user to have it able to send automated envelopes.

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two questions:

1. **How long consent would last?** - forever. Or if you go and explicitly remove it.
2. **Is it the correct way to achieve what I want?** I don't know what you want, but the title says "Sending envelopes from one dedicated user" so, in theory that is correct. However, keep in mind that that user will be different when you move to production ("go live") when your application is ready for real usage.

Comment: What I want is in the title as you said, having one dedicated DS user who will be used for creating and sending envelopes by our back end. Which way would you suggest for it, giving admin consent to that user or just granting one consent manually then using it for automated envelopes? 

So when we go live, I need to create another user in live env and grant consent manually once then it will last forever and be used for automated envelopes again. 

How can I explicitly remove it the consent by the way? 

Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: Regarding removing consent first, from the top-right icon menu select "My Profile" and then Connected Apps and find the one you want and click "Revoke."

Comment: As for your other question. It depends on the requirements. Doing it with a single user is just fine, assuming you are ok with all envelopes sent by that user. If you want to have different users send, you will need to consider using app level consent. Regardless, consent is needed once per user and then you can use this approach to keep sending envelopes.

Comment: If I answered all your questions - please mark this as answered, if you still have more questions - I would ask you create a new thread. Ask separately.

Comment: Hey Inbar, thank you the answers made everything very clean.